# Install redmine plug-in using docker container

Tags: docker, redmine-plugins

I am able to install redmine using these 2 commands.

```
docker run --name myred1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=india -e MYSQL_DATABASE=redmine -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d  -v /storage/mysql/datadir:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:5.6

docker run --name abt -p 3000:3000 -v /my/own/datadir:/usr/src/redmine/files --link myred1:mysql -d redmine
```

But how do I install scrum plugin?

http://www.redmine.org/plugins/scrum-plugin

As per Installation notes...

Download from Files section in the plugin page.

As any Redmine plugin, just deploy it in the plugins folder, ensure folder name is just scrum and then run:

```
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate
```

I tried the above command at command prompt (within docker container)

```
root@d7b535b9c607:/usr/src/redmine/plugins/scrum# bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate
(in /usr/src/redmine)
```

But it does not installs the plug-in.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can preserve plugins between container recreations by adding additional data volumes to keep them. Since spawning docker containers without `docker-compose` is a pain, let me use it for further explanation.

#### 1. Create `docker-compose.yml` describing your setup

It should create two services (one for each of MySQL and Redmine) in a separate bridged network:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  redmine-network:

volumes:
  redmine-plugins:
  redmine-themes:
  redmine-data:

services:
  mysql-for-redmine:
    image: mysql:5.6
    networks:
      - redmine-network
    volumes:
      # Consider using separate volume containers
      # instead of host directory mounts.
      - /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - /storage/mysql/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "<india>"
      MYSQL_DATABASE:      "redmine"

  redmine:
    image: redmine:3.3-passenger
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - redmine-network
    volumes:
      - redmine-plugins:/usr/src/redmine/plugins
      - redmine-themes:/usr/src/redmine/public/themes
      - redmine-data:/usr/src/redmine/files
    environment:
      # Host name matches the MySQL container name.
      REDMINE_DB_MYSQL:        "mysql-for-redmine"
      REDMINE_DB_USERNAME:     "root"
      REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD:     "<india>"
      REDMINE_SECRET_KEY_BASE: "..."
    restart: always
```

#### 2. Deploy your config

Simply run `docker-compose up -d` from the directory where you put your configuration file.

#### 3. Install your plugins (and themes) manually

Find the name of the container running Redmine with `docker ps`; on my system it's `root_redmine_1`. Run the following to attach into it:

```
# docker exec -ti root_redmine_1 gosu redmine bash
```

It will open a shell for "redmine" user inside the container. Use `wget` and `tar xjf` to download and extract plugins you need. Exit the shell when it's done.

#### 4. Restart your instance to check if plugins work

Cast `docker restart root_redmine_1` command and see if it's working as supposed. Since the plugins are put on a separate data volume, they should survive container recreation as well.

Comment: In case of environment variables, can I use consistent syntax like - REDMINE_DB_MYSQL=  instead of REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: ?

Comment: I understood this. # environment does not accept = because it is a dictionary just like image. volumes and ports are lists.

Comment: Before you `bundle install`, you might need to `apt update & apt install make gcc`.

Comment: If you are using `docker-compose`, you don't need to formulate the `docker` command directly. Use `docker-compose exec redmine bash`, `docker-compose restart`.

Answer (score 6):

No need to explain what was said at the docker-composer level

```
version: '3'
services:

  redmine:
    image: redmine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - REDMINE_DB_MYSQL=mysql_redmine
      - REDMINE_DB_USERNAME=root
      - REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD=pass
      - REDMINE_PLUGINS_MIGRATE=true
    volumes:
      - ./redmine_data:/usr/src/redmine/files
      - ./redmine-plugins:/usr/src/redmine/plugins

  mysql_redmine:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=redmine
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data_red:/var/lib/mysql
```

The environment variable `REDMINE_PLUGINS_MIGRATE` gives the possibility to migrate directly your plugins !
also there is no need to enter in the container

Now you just need to use `git submodule add` with your plugin git repository in `./redmine-plugins`

Answer (score 3):

```
# if the name of the redmine container is abt then use the following command to login:
docker exec -it abt bash

# change to plugins directory
cd plugins

# download source code
wget https://redmine.ociotec.com/attachments/download/440/scrum%20v0.16.2.tar.gz

# extract
tar xvf scrum\ v0.16.2.tar.gz

# install
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate

# restart container: 
docker restart abt
```

Comment: Doing things this way you're going to lose all your plugins on container recreation.

Comment: Can I commit the container and create a new image with all my plug-ins?